# How to Programatically change UItextfield Placeholder and text to right alignment

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am doing localization of Arabic in which i have to do text from right to left.
No i dont wont to use POD or Bundle.I am doing at runtime using CountryPicker for selecting Country.

for label i did using below code which is working

```
self.userNameLbl.textAlignment = .right
```

and i have used

```
UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

still no use

Comment: No use for what? You have not explained what the problem is.

Comment: "No i dont wont to use POD or Bundle.I am doing at runtime using CountryPicker for selecting Country." This is a really bad idea. Localization is built into iOS. You are going to be fighting a difficult battle to not do localization the way Apple intended it. Note that you can always do a mix: use built-in localization mechanisms as much as possible, and write custom code (with locale-detection) to fix the parts of your app that still need work.

Comment: My requirement from Client is to use API for 13 languages which i have to do localization of,  almost all languages are done except Right to Left  for Arabic. if i use UITextField.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft  it wont reflect on that screen but it will reflect on next screen.

Answer (score 1):

i am a little confused with your question you want to change the Alignment of textfield or label but for text field i used this and its working you have to create an outlet for your textfild first or define it in a variable

```
NameTextField.textAlignment = .right
```

Answer (score -1):

```
go to storyboard -> select your textfield -> attributes inspector -> view -> semantic set to forceRightToLeft.
```

Comment: setting the attribute in IB is the same as the code the OP posted that supposedly doesn't work. Also IB won't work dynamically since they want the language to dynamically change from left-to-right to right-to-left

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center;
```

Or, for shorthand:

```
label.textAlignment = .center;
```

Swift 3

```
label.textAlignment = .center
```

or

You can set the placeholder text using an attributed string. Pass the color you want with the attributes:

```
var myTextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30))
myTextField.backgroundColor = .blue
myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text",
                         attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow])
```

For Swift 3+ use following:

```
myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text",
                         attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```

For Swift 4.2 use following:

```
myTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "placeholder text",
                         attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```